# WPF <StatusBar> is not positioned at the bottom of the window

Tags: wpf

We have a WPF executable that creates a  and then dynamically loads several assemblies. Each assembly represents a screen (.xaml) that is displayed in one of the tabs. The Problem is that the  is right under the  and not at the bottom of the window. How do I force the  to always be at the bottom of the 
window? Thx!

```
UserControl    
    DockPanel
        CheckBox 
        StatusBar
    DockPanel
UserControl
```

Answer (score 15):

In addition to ArsenMkrt's answer about including the DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" attribute, don't forget that the LAST element in a DockPanel will fill the area unless you explicitly tell it otherwise using a height command (regardless of the DockPanel.Dock attribute provided).

my suggestion is to do thus:

```
<UserControl>
   <DockPanel>
     <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
     <CheckBox />
   </DockPanel>
</Usercontrol>
```

Comment: re: your comment on the last element, you can also set the LastChildFill property on DockPanel

Comment: @qntmfred - you're right. I forget about that attribute, mainly due to the fact that I usually want the last child to fill.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem just now. Thanks to Stephen Wrighton's tip that **the last** element **added** to a `DockPanel` fills the area left over, I figured out how to set up my `Window`. It was a bit weird since I added the `Grid` last but it was positioned in the middle.

```
<Window>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <StatusBarItem Content="Filler" />
        </StatusBar>

        <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">

        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case adding **DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"** was not enough I was forced to add **VerticalAlignment="Bottom"** as well.

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
<StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<DockPanel Grid.Row="0"/>

<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <StatusBar>Status Text</StatusBar>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the order of how I put the children into the `Dockpanel` had an influence. So, this was the correct order to fill proberly:

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="50">Top</Button>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="50">Bottom</Button>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="50">Left</Button>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">Right</Button>
```